# Syntax complication with hash(#) in C programming

Tags: c, macros

In FreeRTOS, it is found an interesting use of hash.

```
#define osThreadDef(name, thread, priority, instances, stacksz)  \
osThreadDef_t os_thread_def_##name = \{ #name, (thread), (priority), (instances), (stacksz)  }
```

I didn't really get the meaning of hash with before name. And there are two hashes and single hash. What does it mean? I searched through internet, but couldn't find anything satisfactory. Thank you.

Comment: Try Googling for these terms:`#` = **stringify**, `##` = **token pasting**.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification

Comment: gcc [token concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) and [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`##` and `#`** --  **C Macro Operators that Simplify Initializing Memory (as well as being applicable in other creative ways limited only by one's imagination)**

`##` is concatenation and `#` takes the associated `#define` macro parameter and substitutes the unquoted parameter input as a null-terminated string (e.g. puts the parameter text in double-quotes `""` (see example below).  That is very useful in some cases to create powerful macros that can help initialize struct arrays to save typing and make the code more concise and readable.

```
#define osThreadDef(name, thread, priority, instances, stacksz)  \
osThreadDef_t os_thread_def_##name = \{ #name, (thread), (priority), (instances), (stacksz)  }
```

Based on that definition we can assume it's written to help initialize a structure whose definition looks something like this:

```
typedef struct osThreadDef {
   char *threadName;
   thread_t *threadPtr;
   int threadPrio;
   int threadInstanceCnt;
   int stackSize;
} osThreadDef_t;
```

Example of using the macro in code:

```
osThreadDef(foobar, &myThr, 5, 10, 100);
```

That would result in this after pre-processing:

```
osThreadDef_t os_thread_def_foobar = { 
    "foobar", &myThr, 5, 10, 100 };
```

In reality, the macro expansion would result in `( )` around the each of last four arguments, but I didn't show that because would just clutter the example. They're added to each parameter in the macro to keep macro-expansion from creating some weird problems in some corner cases, where strange stuff is passed to the macro.

Wrapping macro arguments in ( ) is often done for safety because some kinds of arguments can be problematic. But simple cases like the example don't really require each argument to be wrapped in parenthesis.

Comment: I actually understood that, this variable is converted into char. But my curiosity was how does it happen? I would be grateful if you explain it a little more. thank you. @nerdist colony

Comment: It's called the C pre-processor.  Before a C program is compiled the source code is run through a translation engine  that substitutes `#define` macros.  After that is done the code is 'physically` changed.  The text has literally been substituted into the code. After the `#define` are all substituted, the resulting text is sent to the compile phase. Google  C preprocessing for more detail.  That's why `#define` statements are called macros. Macros usually do that kind of thing in sw eng.  Macro means kind of 'outside the scope' or the meta view, i.e., the big picture or higher level view.